# Is it safe to pass variable created into function to closure?

Tags: swift

Everyone knows standard situation with retain cycle.

```
class TestClass {

    var aBlock: (() -> ())? = nil

    let aConstant = 5


    init() {
        print("init")
        aBlock = {
            print(self.aConstant)
        }
    }

    deinit {
        print("deinit")
    }


}

var testClass: TestClass? = TestClass()
testClass = nil
```

but what about situation like this:

```
class A {

    let b: B
    let c: C

    init() {
        b = B()
        c = C()
    }

    func foo() {
        let localC = c
        b.bar {
            localC.execute()
        }
    }
}
```

`B`, `C` are classes.

I copied `c` and passed into `b.bar` closure as `localC`. In my opinion this situation does not create retain cycle and there will be no problems with deallocation of A.

But I am not 100% sure and I want to ask some with more experience about this. Someone could explain me what happens with references? Tnx.

Comment: The `C` instance *might* be retained by `B` (if it stores the closure passed to `b.bar`), but even if it does, the `C` instance doesn't appear to hold a reference to `self`, so there's no cycle. If the `C` instance did hold a reference to `self`, then yes there'd be a retain cycle, but that would be the case regardless of what you did with the closure passed to `b.bar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you set it up should not create any retain cycles.

`localC` is unnecessary. All that does is create another reference to the underlying instance of `c`. They are identical. Modifying `localC` would also modify `c`. They point to the same object. You would have to explicitly `copy()` in order for them to point to different objects.

With that in mind, this is a diagram of the references:

[image: references]

As you can see, there is no retain cycle being created.